# How can I get a file into an array with a PHP function?

Tags: php

I have a text file called "product.txt" that includes some products:

```
Porsche Bike^A bike with a brand name!^10,000
Pretty Shoes^Come to our shoe store^54.45
Pie Fest!^Oh yeah this is officially the best pie ever^3.45
Inside Out Umbrella^Designer Umbrellas for low cost =^14.55
Coffee^Come get your morning dessert^4.59
```

I want to put them into an array with a function:

```
function loadFile() {
    $filename = ('product.txt');
    $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = trim(fgets($file));
        return $array = explode("^", $line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

The problem with my function is that it won't put all of the products into the array, but only the first line!

Comment: You're returning inside the loop. That's why you only get the first line.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your particular solution but something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php might be better than coding it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

```
function loadFile() {
    $line = array();
    $filename = ('product.txt');
    $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line[] = trim(fgets($file));
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $line;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the OP wants to create a multidimensional array, so I guess it should be: `$line[] = explode("^", trim(fgets($file)));`